# Error /invalidfileaccess in --run-- ,when you are using external files with pst-solides3d

Tags: pst-solides3d

Texmaker use and want to compile latex + dvips + ps2pdf + view pdf but I get the error shown in the image. Can you give me step by step solution to compile as I want.

[image]

Error: /invalidfileaccess in --run-- Operand stack: --nostringval--(biconepartcircle1-sommets.dat)(r) Execution stack: %interp_exit.runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 % stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 % stopped_push 1916 1 3 % oparray_pop 1915 1 3 % oparray_pop 1899 1 3 % oparray_pop 1787 1 3  % oparray_pop --nostringval-- %errorexec_pop .runexec2--nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 % stopped_push--nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 1916 2 9 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- Dictionary stack: --dict:1175/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)-- --dict:118/200(L) -- -- dict:747/1012(L)-- --dict:187/300(L)-- --dict:38/200(L)-- --dict:206/300(L)-- --dict:747/1012(L)-- --dict:747/1012(L)-- --dict:1/1(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: No such file or directory Current file position is 396840 GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error , exit code 1

Comment: Please type in the text of the error. The text will greatly improve searchability over an image.

Comment: Null ... add the error as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Ghostscript in unsafe mode

```
ps2pdf -dNOSAFER ...
```

Otherwise reading and writing file access is suppressed.

Comment: Alex, where I write ps2pdf -dNOSAFER in Texmaker ? Or where?

Comment: I wanted to use the solution
 GPL Ghostscript X.XX : Unrecoverable error exit code 1

 ** WARNING ** Filtering file via command - > ps2pdf -dCompatibilityLevel = 1.5
 -sPAPERSIZE = A0 = false -dGrayImageFilter -dAutoFilterGrayImages = / FlateEncode -
 dAutoFilterColorImages = false -dColorImageFilter = / FlateEncode

edit the file ... / texlive / 20XX / texmf / dvipdfmx / dvipdfmx.cfg the option to insert into the line -dNOSAFER With ps2pdf

D " ps2pdf -dCompatibilityLevel =% v -dNOSAFER -sPAPERSIZE = a0 ... but there is no line in the file dvipdfmx.cfg

Comment: i tried to $> gs -dNOSAFER monfichier.ps quit.ps in console of ubuntu, but not funtion, the console produce error,any idea?

Comment: The console produce:
Error: /undefinedfilename in (monfichier.ps)
Operand stack:Execution stack:
%interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:--dict:1172/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)----dict:77/200(L)--Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: No such file or directoryGPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Comment: I made the error, add ps2pdf-dNOSAFER %.ps no space between ps2pdf and -dNOSAFER ... to add ps2pdf -dNOSAFER %.ps function ...  thank you very much for you answer